# How can I realize "find" with using "$in" by two parameters in mangoose?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Hi I have the function which get object with id array like this.

```json
{
  "participants": [
    "5fa566b5b96a9407c804ccd4",
    "5fa5639cb96a9407c804ccce"
  ]
}
```

And I need to find object which have exactly this fields
Objects in which i try to find it looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fac288e53a6a72e94f721fa"),
  "participants" : [ 
      ObjectId("5fa566b5b96a9407c804ccd5"), 
      ObjectId("5fa5639cb96a9407c804ccc5")
  ],
  "messages" : [],
}
```

I am trying to do like this but it doesn't work.

```js
async filterDialog(newDialog: any){
  const res = await Dialog.find({
    'participants': { $in: { ...newDialog.participants } }, function(err: any, dialog: any) {
      if (err) {
        return err
      } else {
        return dialog
      }
    },
  })
  return res;
}
```

Will be glad if someone help me.

Comment: Can you post in input and expected output? I don't understand exactly what you want. Given an array of `participants` (first block of code) return an object which contains these values? But theexample documents don't have any `participants`_id.

Comment: In filterDialog(newDialog: any) newDialog is the array of two Id users and by this two id's I have to find dialog where this two id's exist but if in the collection of dialogs dialog between this id's doesn't exist I have to return an empty object

Comment: Ok, and has to match the entire array? Or only one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator.

Check this query:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "participants": {
    "$all": yourArray
  }
})
```

Only return the document where the field `participants` contains all element from the given array.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JlneC3K86S6) where  I've used numbers instead of `ObjectId` to read easier.

Please check if this is the behavior you expect.